# Spinner is not rotating after upgrading to Angular 11

Tags: angular

I have upgraded my Angular version to 11. And now in my application there is a spinner (Circle-shaped). Earlier it was rotating and now it has stopped rotating. Its just static circle. Below are my files.

*app.scss*

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';


@import "~@ct-tuxedo/tuxedo-bootstrap/css/tuxedo-bootstrap4-theme.css";
@import "~@ct-tuxedo/tuxedo-bootstrap/css/tuxedo-components.css";
@import "~@ct-tuxedo/tuxedo-bootstrap/css/tuxedo-icons.css";
@import "~ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css";
@import "~ng2-tree/styles.css";


@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';

@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.css';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css';

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
menu, ol, ul {
    padding: 0;
}
dl, menu, ol, ul {
    margin: 0;

}
.menu-selector {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.ml-10 {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.mt-6 {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.pl-7 {
    padding-left: 70px;
}
.side-bar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #332b25;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 5004;
    top: 0px;
}
/*Header css overridings*/
.tuxedo_navbar {
    background-color: #0467b3;
    color: #fff;
}
.tuxedo_navbar .profile .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0 !important;
}
.secondary_navigation {
    padding:0px !important;
}
.secondary_navigation .parent_list li a {
    padding: .5rem 1.25rem .5rem 0 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.site-header {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.portal-header {
    background-color: #0467b3;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
    padding:10px;
}

.logo-txt {
    width: 135px!important;
    height: 32px;
    border-width: 0;
}
.divider:after {
    color:#fff;
}
.tuxedo_navbar .navbar-brand img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-width: 0;
}



.main-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
}
.main-nav {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 50px;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50px;
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 30;
    background: #332b25;
    padding: 1rem 0 0 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.side-bar a span {
    background-color: inherit!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:10px 20px 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    display: none;
    left: 46px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.hidden {
    display: none!important;
}
.showFlyOut {
    display: block!important;
}
.mainNavActive {
    border-left: 4px solid #0092ff;
    background-color: #6c6966!important;
}
.side-bar > ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
}
.side-bar > ul > li {
    position: relative;

}
.side-bar > ul > li i {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.side-bar > ul > li a {
    font-weight: 120;
    font-size: 0.55rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.75rem 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: #4e4744;
    margin:1px;
}
.side-bar > ul > li a.active {
    background-color: #6c6966!important;
    border-left: 4px solid #0092ff;
}
.side-container {
    background: white;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul, nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}
#reports {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .pdf-page-canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .pdf-red {
      color: red;
  }
  .excel-green {
      color: green;
  }
  .ppt-orange {
      color: orange;
  }

 /*
Force table width to 100% http://jsfiddle.net/sschauhan/7h5eaeb6/
*/
table.table-fixedheader {
    width: 100%;
}
/*
Set table elements to block mode.  (Normally they are inline).
This allows a responsive table, such as one where columns can be stacked
if the display is narrow.
*/
 table.table-fixedheader, table.table-fixedheader>thead, table.table-fixedheader>tbody, table.table-fixedheader>thead>tr, table.table-fixedheader>tbody>tr, table.table-fixedheader>thead>tr>th, table.table-fixedheader>tbody>td {
    display: block;
}
table.table-fixedheader>thead>tr:after, table.table-fixedheader>tbody>tr:after {
    content:' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
/*
When scrolling the table, actually it is only the tbody portion of the
table that scrolls (not the entire table: we want the thead to remain
fixed).  We must specify an explicit height for the tbody.  We include
100px as a default, but it can be overridden elsewhere.

Also, we force the scrollbar to always be displayed so that the usable
width for the table contents doesn't change (such as becoming narrower
when a scrollbar is visible and wider when it is not).
*/
 table.table-fixedheader>tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100px;

}
/*
We really don't want to scroll the thead contents, but we want to force
a scrollbar to be displayed anyway so that the usable width of the thead
will exactly match the tbody.
*/
 table.table-fixedheader>thead {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
/*
For browsers that support it (webkit), we set the background color of
the unneeded scrollbar in the thead to make it invisible.  (Setting
visiblity: hidden defeats the purpose, as this alters the usable width
of the thead.)
*/
 table.table-fixedheader>thead::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: inherit;
}


table.table-fixedheader>thead>tr>th:after, table.table-fixedheader>tbody>tr>td:after {
    content:' ';
    display: table-cell;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

/*
We want to set <th> and <td> elements to float left.
We also must explicitly set the width for each column (both for the <th>
and the <td>).  We set to 20% here a default placeholder, but it can be
overridden elsewhere.
*/

 table.table-fixedheader>thead tr th, table.table-fixedheader>tbody tr td {
    float: left;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.table-height {
    height: 65vh !important;
}
tr.collapse.in {display: table-row !important}



#approvalCentralTable {
    .icon {
        transform: none!important;
    }
}
.helpText li{
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
.help-list li{
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.activeLinks {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.card .card-header button {
    padding: 0.375rem 1.25rem;
}
.noPadding {
    padding: 0px;
}
.search_box {
    background-color: #307fbd;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.search_header {
    background-color: #0467b3;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.hoverPointer{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.hoverChangeColor:hover{
  background-color: #e0dacc;
}

#typeSelector option::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase; /* change first letter to uppercase */
}
.icon.Document-o.charcoal{
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg  viewBox%3D%222 2 20 20%22  xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cpath d%3D%22M12.778 4c.206 0 .404.077.55.213l5.444 5.09a.704.704 0 0 1 .228.515v8C19 19.023 17.955 20 16.667 20H7.333C6.045 20 5 19.023 5 17.818V6.182C5 4.977 6.045 4 7.333 4zM7.333 5.455c-.43 0-.777.325-.777.727v11.636c0 .402.348.727.777.727h9.334c.43 0 .777-.325.777-.727V10.12l-4.988-4.664zm6.223 3.636h4.666c.43 0 .778.326.778.727 0 .402-.348.727-.778.727h-5.444c-.43 0-.778-.325-.778-.727v-5.09c0-.402.348-.728.778-.728s.778.326.778.727z%22 fill%3D%22%23333333%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E')
}

#RegistrationForm .clear_icon {
  display: none !important;
}

.disabledLink {
    color: #6c6966!important;
}
.capital-text{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#RegistrationForm tux-autocomplete input{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.registrationToolbarButton{
  background-color: #0467b3;
  color:white;
  width: 160px;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border:none;
}

.button:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  color:white;
  background-color: #1B709E;
}

.session-timeout {
    position: sticky;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0467b3;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.message .alert .message_text{
  padding: .5rem !important;
}
.message .alert .message_text h4{
  display: none !important;
}

#approvalCentral .alert .message_text{
    padding: .5rem !important;
  }
#approvalCentral .alert .message_text h4{
    display: none !important;
  }
.ri-export-btn {
    color: #fff !important;
}

.error-tab a{
  background-color: #f2dede !important;
  //color: #a94442!important;
}
.draggable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.treeview-container {
    overflow-y: visible !important;
}
.hideBuildNo {
    color: #0467b3!important;
}
.loader {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.blinking {
    animation:blinkingText 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{     color: #000;    }
    49%{    color:  #EE7822; }
    50%{    color: transparent}
    99%{    color: #FF0000;  }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}
.icon.lock-o.charcoal{
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg  viewBox%3D%222 2 20 20%22  xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cpath d%3D%22M13 16.732V18a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-1.268a2 2 0 1 1 2 0zM18 9h-1V7c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5S7 4.24 7 7v2H6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V11c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM8.9 7c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1s3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1v2H8.9zM18 21H6V11h12z%22 fill%3D%22%23333333%22 fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E')
}

.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bf2155;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.AffirmationAcc{
  padding-left: 38px;
}
.error_txt {
    color: red;
}
/* Global change for tux alert messages/ removing the head */
.alert .message_text h4{
    display: none !important;
  }

#divpopover4 popover-container {
    max-width: none !important;
}

.removeRowPadding {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
input:disabled, select:disabled, textarea:disabled {
    background: #f0f0f0 !important;
    color: #595959 !important;
}

.not-allowedCursor{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

div.filter_options{
  display: none !important; /*this might remove tux-auto-complete's messages*/
}

.disable-background-opacity{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: whitesmoke;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 998;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.vh_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  /* half of #content height*/
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

a.disabled {
  color: gray;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

*home.scss*

```
.home{
  color: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.home p{
  color: #000;
}

.home-padding{
  padding: 10px 60px 10px 60px;
}

.home-heading{
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214,214,214);
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: black;
}

.ma-t20{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ma-t10{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.ma-l10{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.ma-r5{
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.ma-t100{
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.ma-10{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ma-t30{
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ma-t60{
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.ma-tm30{
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.ma-b20{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ma-b10{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ma-b40{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.paraStrong{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.align.center{
  text-align: center;
}

.align.right{
  text-align: right;
}

.home-link{
  color: #0d91e4;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.home-link-disabled{
  color: #848484;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

p.copy{
  color: #848484;
}

.notification-link{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: black;
}

.bottom-border{
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214,214,214);
}

.tooltip{
  max-width: 400px;
}
.home-popover-link{
  color: #0d91e4;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

a:hover   {
  text-decoration:  none;
  color: #0d91e4;
}

#notification ul li, #notification ol li{
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
#notification ul, #notification ol{
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
}

ul.a {
  list-style-type: square;
}

.detailsPopup .tooltip, .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.signin-padding{
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.input-width{
  width: 50%;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.ma-b10{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Any sort of help is appreciated,
Updated code snippets with only home.scss and app.scss

Comment: what is css for 'loader ' class?

Comment: We have not defined any css for this html. Its all from the libraries being defined in package.json.

Comment: i see home.scss and app.scss in your image

Comment: I have updated the code snippets and added just home.scss and app.scss. Have to delete other files because of the number of characters.

Comment: seems like we doesn't have any css to animate loader,you can use bootstrap's spinner, as easy as that